# How to show shopping cart adds and checkouts correctly with Google Analytics sheets extension

Tags: google-analytics, google-workspace

I would like to see the Shopping Cart Adds, Checkouts, and Transactions for a certain segment, so that the results match what I see on the actual GA > Conversions > E-commerce > Shopping Behavior page.

Is it just that this data can't be extracted from GA's Extension at the moment? Or am I configuring it wrong?

I have spent days trying different things. I know I have the segment correct, because when I use `ga:pageviews` or `ga:uniquePageviews` for the segment and run a report, the returned value is exactly what I see in Google Analytics. However, when I use `ga:productAddsToCart` It's very different than the value I expect. I've tried many of the options, (`ga:quantityAddToCart`, for example), too. Nothing's close to what I see in the actual GA page. Wildly different, in fact.

I have also tried things like using `ga:productAddsToCart` as the Metric with `ga:sessions` as a dimension, and I have also tried the reverse. Those cause errors. I have found [this page](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/dimensions-metrics-explorer/) useful for getting syntax but it's very hard to understand how to replicate GA results using the extension. It only lists things without clearly explaining what they are or how they can be combined.